# service bus subscription on topic don't apply filter

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I try to follow the given tutorial at [1](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/#bkmk_HowToReceiveMsgs). I've created one topic with 2 subscriptions on the topics, respectively with the sqlFilter (user_age < 50) and (user_age>= 50). I've a custom property user_age define for messages.
But when I send messages on the topic, both subscriptions receive the same messages which is nonsense!
Any idea?

My code is fully inspired from the one given in the tuto, in the exception that I use this code to receive a message from a given subscription:

```
resultQM = service.receiveSubscriptionMessage("MyTopic", subName, opts);
```

Comment: Could you post the code where you create the 2 subscriptions?

Comment: This is the code for one subscription, the other is similar I've reduce due ti the space... thank you ;)
  
    `SubscriptionInfo subInfo1 = new SubscriptionInfo("High_Ages"); 
              CreateSubscriptionResult result1 = serviceBusContract.createSubscription(topicName, subInfo1); 
               ruleInfo1 = ruleInfo1.withSqlExpressionFilter("user_age >= 50"); 
        
        CreateRuleResult ruleResult = serviceBusContract.createRule(topicName, "High_Ages", ruleInfo1);`

Comment: This code looks OK. Could you also post the code you're using to create an send the message?

Comment: This is the sending message code... `BrokeredMessage message=new BrokeredMessage(body); message.setProperty("name", name); message.setProperty("user_age", Integer.parseInt(age)); double ttl=86400; message.setTimeToLive(ttl); serviceBusContract.sendTopicMessage(topic, message);` name and age values are submitted via a html form

Comment: Could you remove the Integer.parseInt part? And simply have: `message.setProperty("user_age", age);`

Comment: Yes I did it, but it didn't work. I will check the other part of the code, for sure, the problem is elsewhere... Thank you for your reaction :)

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `subName` parm from your method call, like the one in the tutorial shows?  `resultQM = service.receiveSubscriptionMessage("MyTopic", opts);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in that tutorial does not work correctly. Here is the Java code I used to create two subscriptions (LowMessages and HighMessages) that actually filter on the value of a user-defined custom property "MessageNumber". I found this works. Note you need to explicitly give ruleInfo a name ("RULENAME") and you also need to explicitly delete the default "AllMatch" rule for the subscription (or you get no filtering.)

```
  SubscriptionInfo subInfo = new SubscriptionInfo("LowMessages");
  CreateSubscriptionResult result = service.createSubscription("TestTopic", subInfo);
  RuleInfo ruleInfo = new RuleInfo("RULENAME");
  ruleInfo = ruleInfo.withSqlExpressionFilter("MessageNumber <= 3");
  CreateRuleResult ruleResult = service.createRule("TestTopic", "LowMessages", ruleInfo);
  service.deleteRule("TestTopic", "LowMessages", "$Default");

  SubscriptionInfo subInfo2 = new SubscriptionInfo("HighMessages");
  CreateSubscriptionResult result2 = service.createSubscription("TestTopic", subInfo2);
  RuleInfo ruleInfo2 = new RuleInfo("RULENAME2");
  ruleInfo2 = ruleInfo2.withSqlExpressionFilter("MessageNumber > 3");
  CreateRuleResult ruleResult2 = service.createRule("TestTopic", "HighMessages", ruleInfo2);
  service.deleteRule("TestTopic", "HighMessages", "$Default");
```